# JavaFX - How to Create Small Windows Installer Executable (.exe) Application

Tags: windows, maven, javafx, executable

Previously I used JDK 8 + Maven + Launch4j + Inno Setup to bundle JavaFX application to make an executable installer for windows and I get .exe file with size about ~60mb for SIMPLE hello world JavaFX. And then I moved using JDK 11 + Maven + [Java Packager](https://github.com/fvarrui/JavaPackager) and get .exe installer file smaller just about ~30mb.

My question, can we make the .exe installer even smaller then ~30mb?

Comment: We are also using same. But I want to know the installer logging path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can create an executable installer for windows with a size of about ~14Mb, and before packaged using Inno Setup the .exe size is about ~60Mb. This is possible because Gluon provides a built version of GraalVM in this GitHub repository [gluonhq/graal](https://github.com/gluonhq/graal). For full documentation please read this [docs](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_windows).

Also, I create a sample code using Maven in this repo [NMNaufaldo/HelloGraalFX](https://github.com/NMNaufaldo/HelloGraalFX)

Installer after package using Inno Setup

[image]

.exe native image before package using Inno Setup

[image]